# Swagger 2.0 type string formate: date-time does not output yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, iso8601

I have a Spring Boot 2.7 project that uses the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` version 2.4.1 that generates the model for me.

I need the date format to follow `ISO-8601` format which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`, ie `2019-05-31T23:59:59Z`.

But I am getting the format as `2019-05-31T23:59:59+00:00`.

I have the following piece of yaml spec for swagger 2.0.

```yaml
definitions:
  CommandResponse:
    properties:
      requestTime:
        type: string
        format: date-time
```

The documentations I read for swagger is that `format: date-time` should give the ISO format with the `Zulu` suffix. However, I am not getting the `Z` but rater `+00:00`

Is there some configuration I am missing? What do I need to do to get the date format with the Zulu suffix?

Answer (score 0):

I read this was a default but tuns out my spring boot 2.7 project requires explicit config using `spring.jackson.date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`.

Also remember for testing, if you're not spinning up the full application context, the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter needs to be supplied to the MockMvc.